# Local struct variable doesnt get destroyed after return from method

Tags: c++

I have the following code

```
#include <iostream>

struct mystruct
{
    float x;
};

void fun(mystruct* ptr)
{
    mystruct str = {10};
    ptr = &str;
    std::cout<<"bbq";
}

class cls
{
public:
   mystruct* ptr;
   void fun()
   {
        mystruct str = {10};
        ptr = &str;
        std::cout<<"bbq";
   }
};

int main()
{
    mystruct* ptr = new mystruct;
    fun(ptr);
    std::cout<<"bbq";

    cls obj;
    obj.fun();
    std::cout<<"bbq";

}
```

At first pointer ptr is set in function fun to address of local structure. When function returns local structure gets destroyed as expected.

But then there is method in class that does the same with member pointer, but after method retrurns and im back in main member pointer is still set. Aren't method local variables destroyed after method returns ?

Comment: "Aren't method local variables destroyed after method returns ?" Yes, they are.

Comment: [undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: What are you seeing and what do you expect to see?

Comment: Right, in this particular case, nothing goes horribly wrong, but `str` does indeed disappear at the end of `cls::fun`.

Comment: @chris Although I don't see any attempt to de-reference any dangling pointers.

Comment: @chris: I don't see any undefined behavior here.  Memory leaks, yes, and also pointers left containing unusable values, but no undefined behavior.

Comment: @juanchopanza, Ah, I didn't really notice that, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example isn't setting the pointer that was passed, it is setting a local *copy* of the pointer since it was passed by value. You need to pass by reference in order to use the actual argument:

```
void fun(mystruct*& ptr);
```

Local variables *are* destroyed after the function returns. But even after you see a value inside the pointer that was set to a local variable, you can't assume that the local variable was *not* destroyed. If you dereference the pointer any time after assigning it to an expired object, your program then has Undefined Behavior.

Related: [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 1):

The code is pretty strange.  For example in this function:

```
void fun(mystruct* ptr)
{
    mystruct str = {10}; // create a structure
    ptr = &str;  // make ptr point to it
    std::cout<<"bbq";
}
```

`ptr` is being set to something, but then it is never used.  `ptr` is being passed by value so there is no way it can have an effect outside this function.

And here:

```
class cls
{
public:
   mystruct* ptr;
   void fun()
   {
        mystruct str = {10}; // create local variable
        ptr = &str;  // make ptr point to it
        std::cout<<"bbq";
   }
};
```

You are setting the class member `ptr` to point to a local variable, but then that variable is destroyed when the function returns, so `ptr` is left pointing to garbage.  `ptr` isn't being used again in your example, so no harm done, but it is still strange.

And in your main:

```
int main()
{
    mystruct* ptr = new mystruct; // make ptr point do a dynamically allocated object.
    fun(ptr); // call fun with a copy of the pointer
    std::cout<<"bbq";

    cls obj;
    obj.fun();
    std::cout<<"bbq";
    // That object that ptr is pointing to is never deleted.

}
```

There's no particular harm in not deleting something you allocated in this case, since
this is the end of your program, but it's good practice to delete your dynamically
allocated objects in general.

Answer (score 1):

We could induce a failure by doing this:

```
struct mystruct
{
    float x;
    ~mystruct() { x = 99; }
};


class cls
{
public:
   mystruct* ptr;
   void fun()
   {
        mystruct str = {10};
        ptr = &str;
        std::cout<<"bbq";
   }
   void fun2()
   {
       std::cout << ptr->x << std::endl;
   }
};

... 
  obj.fun();
  obj.fun2();
```

Now, it may happen that `obj.fun2();` prints 99, or it may show some random other number, or it may crash. This is because the "use of an object that has been destroyed is undefined behaviour" - undefined behaviour means that the C++ standard does not define what happens, and "anything could happen", including crashing or hanging, or it works "as you expect". But the object will be destroyed. Since the original code doesn't actually USE `ptr` after the object it points to was destroyed, nothing bad happens (in fact, it's not even undefined behaviour in the example code - it is only undefined to "use pointed at object after the object has been destroyed").

Edit:

this code, however:

```
mystruct* ptr = new mystruct;
fun(ptr);
std::cout<<"bbq";
```

causes a memory leak, since `ptr` is never deleted (and if `fun` where to actually modify `ptr` outside of the function itself, e.g by using `mystruct *&ptr` as the argument, then you would have a memory block for `mystruct` that is no longer referenced, which is an even worse memory leak - and of course a value in `ptr` that points to destroyed object, so you can't use `ptr` anyway)